# Removing comments from xml file using Python

Tags: python, xml, file, parsing, comments

I want to remove comments from xml files.

```
strng = os.path.join(input_dir, country_file)
        with open(strng, 'r') as infile:
            data = infile.read()
            data = data.replace("<!-- %", "")
            data = data.replace("UNICEF_INTERNAL_ELEMENT", "")
            data = data.replace("% <", "<")
            data = data.replace("-->", "")
            infile.close( )
        with open(strng, 'w') as infile:
            infile.write(data)
            infile.close( )
```

I am able to remove comments from the file. But then when further in code i am trying to use xml.etree 's findall( ) method it gives error last lines are
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

The comment tag looks like `<!-- %UNICEF_INTERNAL_ELEMENT% (Useful Text)-->`
So i have to remove `<!-- %UNICEF_INTERNAL_ELEMENT% and -->` which i am able to do but then why my further code is not able to read xml correctly.
One more thing is that the portion of xml which is inside comment is valid xml but not well formatted. All the nested tags are in one line.

Comment: Can you post the portion of code dealing with the eTree usage?

Comment: It's not related to the error you're having, but the use of a `with` block means you don't have to do the file `close()` - leaving the block will do that for you for anything `open()`ed with `with`

Comment: self.provider = names.alias(transaction_xml.findall("provider-org/narrative")[0].text )  
This is the code. transaction_xml contains that xml tree it is coming from other modules